# How can I create a strategy in Renko charts that forces a buy based on OHLC data?

Tags: pine-script

Currently, the strategy on renko charts, buys at the open and close of the renko, which may not be the current market price at the time of execution, what is the best way to force the strategy to make execution on OHLC data, or simple bar chart data ..

Answer (score 0):

If I understood, you want to execute your strategy on the renko but you want to use the OHLC data from a normal candle chart, if this is the case you can use the `request.security()` function to request OHLC data from a regular chart.